# Is "to sport ivory" actually forgotten English?

Tags: meaning, expressions, slang

I saw on a website that there used to be a verb phrase called "to sport ivory", which meant to smile, essentially showing your teeth/ivory.

Did this actually exist or is the website incorrect?

Comment: I'm sure that, in the right context, I'd understand what it meant. But I never heard of it, and I don't think I'll start using it from now on. Also, a quick NGram search turns up nothing.

Comment: Ivory can come from an animal's teeth and has been used to create denture for humans.  So I could see ivory being used to refer to a smile.  And we already know that sport as a verb is still used.  But I also could not find any reference to this particular phrase having existed.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: "Sport Ivory" makes it look like a noun (almost like "sweatpants"). "To sport ivory" makes it clear that we're looking at a verb, and this is the usage you're talking about.

Comment: Expressions such as "show your ivories" used to be common ways to say "smile", though I've heard them less of late.  "Sport ivories" itself would not likely be considered an idiom.

Answer (score 9):

J.S. Farmer & W.E. Henley, [*Slang and Its Analogues Past and Present*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JKRBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA322&dq=%22sport+ivory%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_2PfD0rDWAhVil1QKHQJ-C74Q6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22sport%20ivory%22&f=false), volume 6 (1903) points out that "sport ivory" was part of a brief eruption of expressions of the form "sport X" (where *sport* was used as a verb and X was any of a number of nouns or phrases) that began in the early to middle 1780s. Here is Farmer & Henley's entry for the verb *sport* as a slang term:

> [**Sport**] *Verb.* (old.)—Generic for display : 'the word was in great vogue ... in 1783 and 1784' (GROSE); now-a-days still general, but spec. a public school and university usage. Thus TO SPORT (or BAULK) a report = to publish far and wide; TO SPORT (= drive) A GIG; TO SORT (= wear) NEW TOGS; TO **SPORT IVORY** = to grin; TO SPORT (= exhibit) TEMPER; TO SPORT OAK (TIMBER, or TO SPORT IN) = to deny oneself to callers by closing an outer door ... TO SPORT OFF = to do with ease; TO SPORT (= provide) A DINNER; TO SPORT LITERATURE = to write a book; TO SPORT (= spend) MONEY, ONE'S SALARY, &c.; TO SPORT (= express) AN OPINION; ... TO SPORT SILK (racing) = to ride a race; TO SPORT (= indulge or engage in) SMOKING, WALKING, &c. Whence (Winchester) A SPORTING ACTION = an affected manner, gesture or gait, or a betrayal of emotion.

In the context of the geyser of *to sport* expressions that emerged during and after the great vogue, "to sport ivory" seems less a striking turn of phrase than just another sported-up expression.

The quotation from Francis Grose appears in Grose's [*A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4HoSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PT163&dq=%22lingo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eAhtU7r1A5ChogTl2IGYBA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20sport%22&f=false), second edition (1788):

> TO SPORT. To exhibit : as, Jack Jehu sported a new gig yesterday; I shall sport a new suit next week. To sport or flash one's ivory ; to shew one's teeth. To sport timber ; to keep one's outside door shut ; this term is used in the inns of court to signify denying one's self. N. B. The word *sport* was in great vogue ann. 1783 and 1784.

I see no reason to doubt the specificity of the 1783 and 1784 dating by Grose, given that his book recording the phenomenon appeared only four or five years later.

The first edition of [*A Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zLAJs0_prpwC&pg=PT129&dq=%22lingo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eAhtU7r1A5ChogTl2IGYBA#v=onepage&q=Flash&f=false) (1785), in contrast, has no entry for "to sport"—presumably because Grose had not had time to record the ongoing vogue. But the alternative expression "to flash ivory" receives full attention in the earlier book:

> FLASH, a periwig ; rum flash, a fine long wig ; queer flash, a miserable weatherbeaten caxon ; flash also means to show ostentatiously ; to **flash one's ivory**, to laugh and shew one's teeth ; don't flash your ivory but shut your potatoe trap and keep your guts warm, the devil loves hot tripes.

It thus appears that *ivory* for "human teeth" was already well established during the *flash* vogue preceding the *sport* vogue of 1783–1784. So when the latter mania took hold, coining "to sport ivory" must have been as easy and obvious as falling off a log.

Comment: It is really important that the OP does not get the impression from this answer that the plain use of "sport" in this sense is not currently understood or "went out" in the 18th century. A google search for "Sporting new kicks" comes up with *headlines from news outlets* within the past year. Only mention because the quotes say it.

Comment: @Yorik: Yes—the use of _sport_ as verb meaning "to display" has become a part of standard English, even though "sport ivory" (the phrase that the poster asks about) has given way to such alternatives as "flash [one's] pearly whites."

Comment: OP here - Thank you so much! You're a life saver :) @SvenYargs

Answer (score 3):

As a verb, *sport* is defined (in Google) as:

> wear or display (a distinctive or noticeable item).
>
> "he was sporting a huge handlebar mustache"
>
> synonyms: wear, have on, dress in; display, exhibit, show off,
>   flourish, parade, flaunt
>
> "he sported a beard"

Thus, "sport ivory" is to show off your teeth with a wide smile.

Comment: I believe they are asking if this phrase was commonly used in the past.

Comment: "to sport" in the sense of the dictionary definition quoted is a verb that can take many objects.  If you want to provide an answer about frequency, please do.

Comment: I'm just suggesting that while you're discussing a related topic, your "answer" did not actually answer the question.